# Python package for quantum computations based on symbolic variables

Tags: programming, resource-request, qutip

I am searching for a quantum package in Python that can enable me to calculate, for example, a density matrix symbolically and display the results in variable form rather than numerically. I am aware of `QuTiP`, but it is primarily designed for numerical applications.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of a density matrix you want to calculate symbolically? I have had some luck combining sympy with Qiskit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`qiskit-symb`](https://github.com/SimoneGasperini/qiskit-symb), which is a Python package.

You may also take a look this, which is not a Python package, but you might find it helpful: [Wolfram Quantum Framework](https://www.wolfram.com/quantum-computation-framework/) provide-

- [Symbolic computation for quantum states](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/ExampleRepository/resources/Symbolic-computation-for-quantum-states/)
- [Symbolic computation for quantum circuits](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/ExampleRepository/resources/Symbolic-computation-for-quantum-circuits/)
- [Symbolic evolution of a quantum state](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/ExampleRepository/resources/Symbolic-evolution-of-a-quantum-state/)

Answer (score 3):

The [pytket](https://tket.quantinuum.com/api-docs/) package has utility functions for doing symbolic manipulations with quantum circuits. See the docs for [pytket.utils.symbolic](https://tket.quantinuum.com/api-docs/utils.html#module-pytket.utils.symbolic).

Here's how you'd get the symbolic unitary of a small circuit.

```python
from pytket import Circuit
from pytket.circuit.display import render_circuit_jupyter as draw
from pytket.utils.symbolic import circuit_to_symbolic_unitary
from sympy import symbols

a, b = symbols("a b")
circ = Circuit(2)
circ.X(0).CRy(a, 0, 1).Rz(b, 0) 

draw(circ) # Draw circuit diagram
circuit_to_symbolic_unitary(circ) # Get the symbolic unitary matrix
```

[image]
[image]